# getting Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest' after I did required firebase setup for flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

I cloned a flutter project which require firebase, so I created new firebase project and added required 'google-services.json' file in 'android/app/' folder. But now getting this error and could not understand what is wrong.

[error image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZyvx.png)

I followed this video for configuring firebase for this flutter project: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sz4slPFwEvs

can anybody help me in running this flutter project?
cloned flutter project: https://github.com/Meet-Turakhia/Makeat